# How to organize subroutines for use by multiple commands?

Tags: stata

I am working on creating a package with two new commands, say `foo` and `bar`.

For example, if `foo.ado` contains:

```
program define foo
    ...
    rex
end

program define rex
    ...
end
```

But my other command, `bar.ado`, also needs to call `rex`. Where should I put `rex`?

I see the following few options:

1. Create a `rex.ado` file as well.
2. Create a `rex.do` file and include it from within both `foo.ado` and `bar.ado` using `` include "`c(sysdir_plus)'r/rex.do" `` at the bottom of each file.
3. Copy the code into both `foo.ado` and `bar.ado`, which seems ugly because now the code must be maintained in two places.

What is best practice for organizing subroutines that are needed by both `foo` and `bar`?

Also, should the subroutine be called `rex`, `_rex`, or something else — maybe `_foobar_rex` — to indicate it is actually a sub-command that `foo` and `bar` depend on to work correctly rather than a separate command intended to stand on its own?

Comment: Answers also depend on (1) Who is using your code? For example, are they likely to be comfortable with the need to update if you imagine revising the code in the future? (2) Who is reading your code? Are they likely to be troubled by your personal naming conventions? (3) How likely is that `rex` is needed by itself?

Comment: These are all valid points but it is hard giving solid advice when the question is so general.

Comment: @ChrisP did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: @PearlySpencer, thanks for the answer. Accepted. It seems collisions are a big risk without a package level namespace; I will have to choose names carefully because two user-written commands might have a `rex.ado` file. As far as I can tell, there is no way to have `user_cmd1.rex` and `user_cmd2.rex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create a rex.ado file as well

Your question is a bit too broad. Personally, I would go with the first option to be safe, although it really depends on the structure of your project. Sometimes including `rex` in a single `ado` file may be enough. This will be the case, for example, if `foo` is a wrapper command. However, for most other use cases, including two commands sharing a common program, i strongly believe that you will need to have a separate `ado` file.

The second option is obviously unnecessary, since the first does the same thing, plus it does not have to load the program every single time you call it. The third option is probably the worst in a programming context, as it may create conflicts and will be difficult to maintain down the road.

With regards to naming conventions, I would recommend using something like `_rex` *only* if you include the program as a subroutine in an `ado` file. Otherwise, `rex` will do just fine and will also indicate that the program has a wider scope within your project. It is also better, in my opinion, to provide a more elaborate explanation about the intended use of `rex` using a comment at the start of the `ado` file, rather than trying to incorporate this in the name.